# count number of rows in one df depending on column in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok so I have a first dataframe df1:

```
|timestamp                |ip         |
|2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00|1.1.1.5.   |
|2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00|10.10.10.24|
|2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00|3.3.3.89.  |
|2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00|8.8.8.88.  |
```

And a second dataframe, df2:

```
|timestamp                |other|
|2022-01-07 22:08:59+00:00|other|
|2022-01-07 23:08:59+00:00|other|
|2022-01-09 17:04:09+00:00|other|
|2022-03-05 17:04:09+00:00|other|
```

And I would like to count how many rows there is in df2 depending on the 2 consecutive timestamps in df1, meaning:

```
|timestamp                |ip         |count|
|2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00|1.1.1.5    |NaN  |
|2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00|10.10.10.24|2    |
|2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00|3.3.3.89   |1    |
|2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00|8.8.8.88   |1    |
```

What I tried is to first create another column in df1 with the previous timestamp with this:

```
df1 = df1.assign(timestamp_b4=df1.timestamp.shift(1)).fillna({'timestamp_b4': df1.timestamp})
```

which gives me:

```
|timestamp                |ip         |timestamp_b4             |
|2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00|1.1.1.5    |2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00|
|2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00|10.10.10.24|2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00|
|2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00|3.3.3.89   |2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00|
|2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00|8.8.8.88   |2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00|
```

and then do some sort of

```
s = (df2[df2['timestamp'].between(df1['timestamp'], df1['timestamp_b4'])].size())
```

But unfortunately it does not work since pandas requires comparing identically-labeled objects.

Is there a good pandas/pythonic way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be good to use "df.loc" and see how many records you are looking for, and accordingly insert it in the line, all this using apply

Comment: I believe your example, the first and second dataframe don't contain any similar data

Comment: @RafaelMRdeRezende why should it represent the same data? First dataframe is vpn deconnections timestamps and second dataframe is number of attempted scans when connected to the vpn. I want to have the number of attempted scans associated with the deconnection line

Comment: Well, at one point we need something to compare to. Could you explain to me why "10.10.10.24" should return a count of 2, but "1.1.1.5" NaN instead of 1?

Comment: @Drakax it is not about ip but about timestamps. In my example, it returns 2 at timestamp `2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00` because before `2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00` but after `2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00` there are 2 connections in df2, one at `2022-01-07 22:08:59+00:00` and one at `2022-01-07 23:08:59+00:00` and it returns NaN (or zero) at `2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00` because there is no connection before this date in df2 (but it could be X if there were X connections in df2 before this timestamp)

Comment: Ok so it's not adjacent timestamps but consecutive ones (in df1) between 2 timestamp in df2.

Comment: yes sorry, english mistake :/

Comment: No problem, don't take it personally it was just to be sure ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in the end, here's what I did. I used @Drakax answer.

I created a column with the previous timestamps

```
df1 = df1.assign(previous_deconnection=df1.timestamp.shift(1)).fillna({'previous_deconnection': df1.timestamp})
```

then I set the first row value,

```
df1['previous_deconnection'].iloc[0]=pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01 00:00:00+00:00')
```

then I apply this function to each row of df1

```
def time_compare(a,b):  
  return len(b[((b['timestamp'] >= a['previous_deconnection']) & (b['timestamp'] <= a['timestamp']))])

df1['Count'] = df1.apply(lambda row: time_compare(row, df2), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.  Note that columns from df1 are retained in the final output df:

Starting with this df1 that has an additional column:

```
                   timestamp           ip another_col
0  2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00     1.1.1.5.       val_1
1  2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00  10.10.10.24       val_2
2  2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00    3.3.3.89.       val_3
3  2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00    8.8.8.88.       val_4 

df1.merge(df2, on='timestamp', how='outer').sort_values('timestamp') \
    .assign(c1=df1.loc[~df1['ip'].isna()]['ip'], c2=lambda x: x['c1'].bfill() ) \
    .assign(count=lambda x: x.groupby('c2').apply('count').reset_index(drop=True)['timestamp']-1) \
    .drop(['other','c1','c2'], axis=1).dropna().astype({'count': 'int32'})

                   timestamp           ip another_col  count
0  2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00     1.1.1.5.       val_1      0
1  2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00  10.10.10.24       val_2      2
2  2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00    3.3.3.89.       val_3      1
3  2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00    8.8.8.88.       val_4      1
```

Note that `another_col` is retained in the output.

This approach merges then sorts by timestamp then creates another column - c2 - that is used to copy the df1 timestamp and then backfill it against the df2 timestamps.  From there the instances are grouped by df1 timestamp (reflected in the c2 column) and counted.  In other words, the backfill of the df1 timestamp allows it to be used as a grouping key for counting the preceding df2 timestamps.   After that the df is trimmed back down to match the output requirements.

Also note that with this approach the dataframes need to be indexed 0-n like they currently are in my example.

Comment: Hello thanks! One question: if I have more column than just `ip` in df1, how should I do? `c1=df1.drop(['timestamp'], axis=1)` ?

Comment: @LaureD This approach preserves additional columns in df1.  I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I already suceeded to do what I wanted but I want to check your answer as well ;) More elegant

Answer (score 1):

```
def time_compare(df1,df2):
  return [np.sum((df1['timestamp'].values[i-1] < df2['timestamp'].values) & (df1['timestamp'].values[i] > df2['timestamp'].values)) for i in range(len(df1.timestamp))]

df2.join(pd.Series(time_compare(df1,df2), name='Count'))
```

Weird I can't post the dataframe output as usual:

| index | timestamp | other | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-07 22:08:5900:00 | other | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-07 23:08:5900:00 | other | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-01-09 17:04:0900:00 | other | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-03-05 17:04:0900:00 | other | 1 |

Comment: @Laure D , I didn't know if returning "0" for "Count" was ok or not, I'll wait for your comment :)

Comment: weird, it is not working with my data (does not give me expected results :/)

Comment: Any error? Which results are returned? I've just checked in my Goole Colab with the data you provided and it worked. Can you double check df names?

Comment: Maybe because the data I gave you as an example is much simpler compared with my actual data? I don't know

Comment: it does not give any error however the count numbers are not good

Comment: Well, probably. Just in case, double check this please: https://ibb.co/Bt5dZB6. I worked on the code you provided so... ^^ You can still update your question if data are not too much different ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's an example of what you can do to find the solution

```py
import pandas as pd
table1 = {
    'timestamp':['2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00','2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00',
                 '2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00','2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00'],
    'other':['other','other','other','other']
              }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(table1)

table2 = {
    'timestamp':['2022-01-07 23:08:59+00:00','2022-01-07 22:08:59+00:00',
                 '2022-03-05 17:04:09+00:00','2022-01-09 17:04:09+00:00'],
    'ip':['1.1.1.5.','10.10.10.24','3.3.3.89.','8.8.8.88.']
    
              }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(table2)

print(f'\n\n-------------df1-----------\n\n')
print(df2)
print(f'\n\n-------------df2-----------\n\n')
print(df1)

listdf1 = df1['timestamp'].values.tolist()
def func(line):
    cont = df1.loc[df1['timestamp'].str.contains(line[0][:7], case = False)]
    temp = line.name - 1
    if temp == -1:
        temp = 0

    try :
        cont = [cont['timestamp'].iloc[temp],line[0]]
    except:
        cont = [line[0],line[0]]

    cont2 = df2['timestamp'].loc[df2['timestamp'].str.contains(line[0][:7], case = False)]
    
    repetitions = 0
    for x in cont2:

        if int(x[8:10]) >= int(cont[0][8:10]) and int(x[8:10]) <= int(cont[1][8:10]) and int(x[8:10]) <= int(line[0][8:10]):
            repetitions += 1
    return repetitions
    

print(f'\n\n-------------BREAK-----------\n\n')

df1['count'] = df1.apply(func, axis = 1)

print(df1)
```

Comment: I am not sure your code works for my problemn why should we compare with line[0] of df2?

Comment: I changed the code to something similar to your problem

Comment: It does not work, it gives me an error: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).`

Comment: apply is pulling the dataframe row where the values ​​are not repeated, so the 'line[0]' is taking the value of the captured row in the first column, which is the 'timestamp' column, this comparison is just for the loc , find all the lines of dataframe 1 corresponding to the 'line' value of dataframe 2, after that I give the 'len' to find how many lines were pulled

Comment: but then it should not be `==` because there is no equal timestamps, I think it should be `between` or something similar

Comment: Do you want to find what similarity? I didn't find any similarity in your example.

Comment: I want to count the number of rows in df2 between 2 timestamps, and the values of these timestamps are the ones in df1. For instance I want to count the number of rows  in df2 between `2022-01-06 11:58:53+00:00` and `2022-01-08 03:56:35+00:00` if I follow my example. So that makes 2 because there is 2 connections on `2022-01-07 22:08:59+00:00` and `2022-01-07 23:08:59+00:00` in df2

Comment: I changed and tried to do what you asked, I think it's close to what you want, it needs some changes to make it work perfectly

Comment: I didn't understand this line in the example: ```|2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00|8.8.8.88 |1 |```

Comment: Because in df2 there is only one connection between `2022-01-09 22:29:30+00:00` and `2022-03-08 22:37:52+00:00` in df2 which is at `2022-03-05 17:04:09+00:00`

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this out, however it is not very pythonic/pandas friendly x)

Comment: I'm kind of new, so I still don't know how to do everything very well structured

Comment: The essential thing in the code itself is ```.str.contains(line[0][:7], case = False)``` it finds a part of a string on a given line. And if you get a typedata error, use ```.astype(str).str.contains(line[0][:7], case = False)```. Maybe with this and the code I made you will find a light

Comment: A friendlier way would be to use the datetime library and try reading about rrule. I have a code that I already used rrule to find periods between certain dates EXAMPLE: ```for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, dtstart=start_date, until=end_date)```